# Remove duplicated from a list based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a list in excel of vendor in excel and I would like that Excel removes my vendor in  duplicate (in column A) based on the following criteria: on  column E, if it is written  "FALSE"  and if excel finds a vendor in duplicate (in column A), excel should remove the duplicate for which the column E is written "FALSE" and keep only the duplicate for which is written "TRUE" in column E.

If someone know how to do that, that would be fabulous (with VBA or not)

[image]

Comment: What defines the conditions of the True/False in column E. You might be able to achieve this with a pivot table

Comment: thanks Tom but unfortunately it does not solve my problem

Comment: How does it not? What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Vendors As Range

    LastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Set Vendors = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A"))

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Vendors, Cells(i, "A").Value) > 1 Then
            If Cells(i, "E") = False Then
                Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to copy the "FALSE" vendors to a different sheet and do there the "remove duplicate" (Data->Data Tools->Remove Duplicates). Then you would copy the result back. If you are concerned about the order of the vendors, rank them first.

Comment: Thanks Peter and thanks to all of you! In fact I realized that my column B,C,D,E includes formulas… that´s why the “Remove Duplicates” functionality did not work properly… What I did: I selected all my data, then copy and paste special value. Finally, I reselected all my data again and press the button “Remove Duplicates” and this time it works like a charm! My problem is solved!